# opening a word document using ms-word:ofe is failing only on my system

Tags: java, c#, ms-word, ms-office, webdav

We have a code on our clients site which opens a MS Word document for editing. We are using the ms-word:ofe office URI scheme for opening the word document.

The problem which i am facing is that this command does not work on my local system.  It opens on all other systems, but not on mine.

I thought that it could be the issue with my local MS Office, so i got it reinstalled. But still i am facing the same issue. I am currently using MS Office 2010.

The request, in Chrome Developer console shows as Cancelled. Some details of the request:

Request URL:ms-word:ofe|u|http://[ourdomain]/webdav/offf60L2K2-kDtYgu9uSeAV/97c6b322-cc1b-4442-bef3-2bfe36ad7148.docx

Would need help with this

Comment: What happens when you click on the link? Is there an error message? If in doubt what's happening on your system, Process Monitor might give you some insight.

Comment: I got the issue resolved. It was because I didn't had the ms office sp2 installed. I got it installed and the issue was resolved